# What is the solution of $\int \sin(x)^2 dx$

Tags: integration

What is the solution of $\int \sin(x)^2  dx$? I have tried partial integration and substitution but haven't got an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

Use $$\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x\implies\sin^2x=?$$

Comment: @user50224, You can also try Integration by Parts $$I=\int\sin^2x\ dx=\sin x\int\sin xdx-\int\left(\frac{d(\sin x)}{dx}\int\sin xdx\right)dx $$  $$\implies I=-\sin x\cos x+\int(1-\sin^2x)dx=-\sin x\cos x+\int\ dx-I$$